# How to check if two PHP sessions is set or not

Tags: php, session

I need to check if this `$_SESSION['1'] || $_SESSION['2']` isset or not

I tried this

```
ob_start();
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['log']) && $_SESSION['log'] !== 1) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['insAdmin']) && $_SESSION['insAdmin'] !== 1) {
        header("Location:sessionManager/login.php");
    }
}
```

but if `$_SESSION['insAdmin']` isset

I get a notes

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: log in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\en\admin\headers.php on line 13

Comment: Your if statement makes no sense. Your first if is: `If $_SESSION['log'] is NOT set AND it's unequal to 1, then enter the if statement`. If the index isn't set it can't have a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're contradicting yourself:

```
!isset($_SESSION['log']) & $_SESSION['log'] !== 1
```

You're basically saying `if $_SESSION['log'] is not set and $_SESSION['log'] is not 1` which doesn't make sense.

If `$_SESSION['log']` is not set then trying to access it's value through  `$_SESSION['log']` (with the 2nd expression after `&&`) will result in an undefined index of course.

You should remove the `!`:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['log']) && $_SESSION['log'] !== 1) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['insAdmin']) && $_SESSION['insAdmin'] !== 1) {
        header("Location:sessionManager/login.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally use isset to test if a variable contains a value before checking it's actual value.

But you check if the variable is NOT set `!isset($_SESSION['log']` and then check it's value which of course will always cause the notice if `log` is not set.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if it's not set, check if it's set instead.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['insAdmin']) && $_SESSION['insAdmin'] !== 1) {
    header("Location:sessionManager/login.php");
}
```